# Will GAE Cron Job wait for previous Cron Job to be completed before running?

Tags: google-app-engine, concurrency, cron

I am wondering whether Cron Jobs ran by Google App Engine wait for the last Cron Job to finish before starting a new Job? What is happening if:

- A Job is schedules to run every minute but one Job instance takes longer than a minute to complete?
- Two different Jobs are schedules to run at the same time (say, every minute)?

Will two Cron Jobs be run in parallel, or will one Job wait for another to complete before being run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you defined the cron job, from the doc

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_The_schedule_format:

> By default, an interval schedule starts the next interval after the last job has completed. If a from...to clause is specified, however, the jobs are scheduled at regular intervals independent of when the last job completed.

If you do not want that behavior, you can add keyword `synchronized`.